# Share_buffer_size in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have a Postgres 9.3 DB on RHEl 6.4. I am getting DB connection time out from a server which is on RHel6.4.

The following data is SAR data when this issue occurred.

```
00:00:01        CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest     %idle
02:10:01        all      0.05      0.00      0.29      3.06      0.00      0.00      0.05      0.00     96.55
02:20:01        all      0.07      0.00      0.28      3.84      0.00      0.00      0.05      0.00     95.75

00:00:01    kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit

02:10:01       781108  65150968     98.82    151576  60250076   5905400      7.17
02:20:01       245712  65686364     99.63    151664  60778552   5905140      7.17
```

The value of “memused” seems to be high, but this value does not include the value of “shared buffer”.
(“kbcached” include the “shared buffer cache memory”.)

Currently, data which is to be exported to server via “shared buffer” of db at once.
This data size is huge.
As the result, db_timeout is occurring.

Shared buffer: memory used when exporting data

Please suggest.

1. Do I need to increase the size of shared buffer.
2. Is it possible that I can divide my data in shared buffer which is to be sent to server.

I analyzed query from db function.

```
kddi=# EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE)
select *
from table, user_data
where user_data.customer_id = charge_history.customer_id
   and charge_history.updated_date::date = (CURRENT_DATE - integer '1')
   and charge_history.picked_status = 'NOTPICKED';

                                                                         QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..10873.44 rows=75 width=271) (actual time=0.123..51.515 rows=3982 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=18475 read=55682
   ->  Index Scan using idx_chrghist_picked_status on charge_history  (cost=0.42..10239.13 rows=75 width=255) (actual time=0.092..16.022 rows=3982 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (picked_status = 'NOTPICKED'::text)
         Filter: ((updated_date)::date = (('now'::cstring)::date - 1))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 10022
         Buffers: shared hit=2547 read=55682
   ->  Index Scan using "CUSTOMERID" on subscriber_data  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=3982)
         Index Cond: ((customer_id)::text = (charge_history.customer_id)::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=15928
Total runtime: 52.053 ms
```

`shared_buffers` setting in DB is 1GB

Can I do something to improve my query.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve data in chunks from shared buffer

Comment: This is unclear. Are you speaking about the database parameter `shared_buffers`? That is shared memory and is different from the file system cache (`kbcached`). Are you sending the data from the client to the database server or the other way round? If you send a lot of data, why do you have a small timeout value?

Comment: Yes i am talking about db perameter shared_buffer.client is trying to fetch data from DB.How shared buffer is calculated.Is there any function/query to fetch small data (in  chunks/blocks ) from shared buffer.

Comment: The client does not receive data from shared buffers directly, but from the database server. To request your data in chunks, split the request in several SQL statements (we still don't know what SQL statement you are running). If you are retrieving a single large binary item, consider using large objects which support streaming.

Comment: I am  using a select query.Could you please explain it with example, if i have 1000 rows in DB table  and i wish to retrieve first 500 rows in first query and second 500 rows in second query and but they both will form a single file in the end,Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id BETWEEN 500 AND 1000` It is up to you to write the file.

Comment: I analyzed query from db function.

kddi=# EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE)

Comment: nested Loop  (cost=0.85..10873.44 rows=75 width=271) (actual time=0.123..51.515 rows=3982 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=18475 read=55682
  ->  Index Scan using idx_chrghist_picked_status on charge_history

Comment: (cost=0.42..10239.13 rows=75 width=255) (actual time=0.092..16.022 rows=3982 loops=1)
Index Cond: (picked_status = 'NOTPICKED'::text)
Filter: ((updated_date)::date = (('now'::cstring)::date - 1))
Rows Removed by Filter: 10022
 Buffers: shared hit=2547 read=55682
 ->  Index Scan using "CUSTOMERID" on subscriber_data  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=3982)
Index Cond: ((customer_id)::text = (charge_history.customer_id)::text)
 Buffers: shared hit=15928
Total runtime: 52.053 ms
Shared_buffers size setting in DB=1GB

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the following index would speed up things by a factor 3 or more:

```
CREATE INDEX ON charge_history(picked_status, (updated_date::date));
```

But you can only create that index if `updated_date` is a `date` or a `timestamp without time zone`, because casting from `timestamp with time zone` to `date` is not [immutable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html) (it depends on the setting of `TimeZone`).

If that is a problem, you could change the query to something like:

```
... AND CAST(charge_history.updated_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date) = ...
```

Then that expression can be indexed, because it is immutable.

The other problem is that the optimizer underestimates how many rows in `charge_history` will be matched. The cause could well be that recent rows tend to have `picked_status = 'NOTPICKED'`. Maybe the solution is to calculate statistics for that table more often.

You might want to experiment with *either* reducing [`autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-ANALYZE-SCALE-FACTOR) for that table *or* setting it to 100 and setting a reasonably high [`autovacuum_analyze_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-ANALYZE-THRESHOLD).
This can be done with an SQL statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE charge_history SET (
   autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 100,
   autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 100000
);
```

This example statement would cause new statistics to be calculated whenever 100000 rows have been modified.

Comment: Thanks Albe.My actual query is like

Comment: select
subscriber_data.customer_id ,
charge_history.charge_trx_id,
charge_history.updated_date,
charge_history.command_tx_id ,
charge_history.mvno_id,
charge_history.customer_id,
charge_history.extra_plan_id,
charge_history.base_plan_id,
charge_history.old_base_plan_id,
charge_history.volume,
charge_history.price,
charge_history.charge_type,
charge_history.remarks
from charge_history , subscriber_data
where subscriber_data.customer_id=charge_history.customer_id and charge_history.updated_date::date=(CURRENT_DATE - integer '1') and 'charge_history.picked_status = 'NOTPICKED';

Comment: That won't make a difference. The interesting information would be the ata type of `charge_history.updated_date`.  Did you try my recommendations?

Comment: Thanks Albe.I cheked the table

Comment: updated_date     | timestamp with time zone
Indexes:
    "CHARGETRXID" PRIMARY KEY, btree (charge_trx_id)
    "idx_chrghist_customer_id" btree (customer_id)
    "idx_chrghist_picked_status" btree (picked_status)

Comment: Probably i can try your recommendation tomorrow will let you know results.Thanks