# EXPLAIN (BUFFER,ANALYZE) understading

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-performance

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 Can some one help me what i can do to improve this. The max number of records in db table is approx 5000 to 7000 varies daily basis. shared_buffers setting in PGsql DB is =1GB. whats wrong here. My query o/p is

```
EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE) 
select sd.customer_id, ch.charge_trx_id, ch.updated_date, ch.command_tx_id, ch.mvno_id,
       ch.customer_id, ch.extra_plan_id, ch.base_plan_id, ch.old_base_plan_id, ch.volume,
       ch.price, ch.charge_type, ch.remarks 
from charge_history ch,
     subscriber_data sd
where sd.customer_id = ch.customer_id
  and ch.updated_date::date = (CURRENT_DATE - integer '1')
  and ch.picked_status = 'NOTPICKED';
```

[plan](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Qgwe):

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..10873.44 rows=75 width=271) (actual time=0.123..51.515 rows=3982 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=18475 read=55682
   ->  Index Scan using idx_chrghist_picked_status on charge_history  (cost=0.42..10239.13 rows=75 width=255) (actual time=0.092..16.022 rows=3982 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (picked_status = 'NOTPICKED'::text)
         Filter: ((updated_date)::date = (('now'::cstring)::date - 1))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 10022
         Buffers: shared hit=2547 read=55682
   ->  Index Scan using "CUSTOMERID" on subscriber_data  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=3982)
         Index Cond: ((customer_id)::text = (charge_history.customer_id)::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=15928
Total runtime: 52.053 ms
(11 rows)
```

Comment: please put your plan https://explain.depesz.com/ and populate link with result

Comment: Query:EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE) select subsc_data.customer_id ,charge_history.charge_trx_id, charge_history.updated_date, charge_history.command_tx_id , charge_history_id, charge_history.customer_id, charge_history.extra_plan_id,charge_history.base_plan_id, charge_history.old_base_plan_id,charge_history.volume, charge_history.price,charge_history.charge_type, charge_history.remarks from charge_history,subscriber_data where subscriber_data.customer_id=charge_history.customer_id and charge_history.updated_date::date=(CURRENT_DATE - integer '1') and 'charge_history.picked_status = 'NOTPICKED';

Comment: How can i improve this query

Comment: run your query. copy the result. paste it to depesz form and click submit. then copy the link and put it to your question please

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Qgwe

Comment: so `charge_history.customer_id` is not indexed?..

Comment: 52 milliseconds to find almost 4000 records. Not bad. How fast should it be, what speed are you looking for?

Comment: You have no problem: your query is using indexes on both tables. If you insist that you want this faster: * upgrade to PG9.6 so you may benefit from parallel query execution; * reduce the size of both tables so more records fit on a single disk page; * buy faster hardware.

Comment: Hi Vao,No its not indexed.Can you suggest.Actually i am a new comer to this.Cann you help me to improve  query.The query is failing might be due to number of records its fetching is quiet large in size(almost=350000).

Comment: You do have indexes and your query returns 3,982 records in 52 ms. Are you sure that you show the correct plan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share\_buffer\_size in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064412/share-buffer-size-in-postgresql)